# How can I apply bones rotation to make sure it is 0 after export?

Tags: rigging, bones

I rigged a model in blender and double-checked that the roll of each bone is 0.

[image: 3D Viewport showing model and armature]

But after I export the model from blender to another software (SparkAR, but it doesn't matter) - the model looks right but the bone rotation is not 0. The Armature and the first bone has X-rotation -90,00001

[image]

How can I fix it, how can I apply bones rotation to make sure it is 0 after export?

Blend file: [image]

Comment: can you add your blend file to your question? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: @MartyFouts I added the Blend file and update the description. Now all bones have 0 rotation except for the armature and the first bone in it.

Comment: File looks good to me.  Perhaps it's a problem with the exporter.  What format do you export it to? obj?

Comment: @MartyFouts FBX

Comment: @MartyFouts Yes, it seems it has something to do with export settings...

Comment: The FBX exporter has known problems with armature rotation, perhaps that's the issue.  Maybe you can check on the SparkAR forums.  People there might be more aware of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, FBX export is set to Maya-like axis setup. In this setup, Y axis points to the top, while Z is rotated to the side. Blender tries to achieve this setup by rotating the model by 90 degrees on the X-axis. So you have an option to set Z-axis as up axis in export settings:

[image]

But in this case, the model will lie on the back in Y-top Maya-like setups.

Other option is "Apply transform" here, that fixes that problem. But it marked as unstable, and I'm not sure if it works with armatures...

Comment: Thank you! yes, changing these settings helped me, as well s applying some patches in SparkAR. Thnk you!